# Systemd Networkd Vlan configuration

Tags: debian, networking, systemd-networkd

I am trying to setup the following using systemd networkd on debian 9:

- Interface eth0 ip address from DHCP server
- Interface vlan5 on eth0 vlan id 5 with static ip address: 172.16.0.1

This is the configuration:

`/etc/systemd/network/20-wired.network`

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
VLAN=vlan5
```

`/etc/systemd/network/vlan5.netdev`

```
[NetDev]
Name=vlan5
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=5
```

`/etc/systemd/network/vlan5.network`

```
[Match]
Name=vlan5

[Network]
DHCP=no
Address=172.16.0.1/24
```

When I execute `ip addr show`:

```
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:a5:04:f1:12:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.31/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 2854sec preferred_lft 2854sec
    inet 192.168.1.85/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a02:a03f:8584:e200:7aa5:4ff:fef1:1246/64 scope global deprecated mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic
       valid_lft 56463sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fe80::7aa5:4ff:fef1:1246/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: vlan5@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:a5:04:f1:12:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.0.1/24 brd 172.16.0.255 scope global vlan5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.243.53/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global vlan5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7aa5:4ff:fef1:1246/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Which confirms that eth0 got an ip address from our dhcp, for whatever reason he even has 2 ip addresses: 192.168.1.31 and 192.168.1.85 but atleast it works.

Vlan5 also has 2 ip addresses: 172.16.0.1/24 and 169.254.243.53/16. If I connect a host on this vlan with ip 172.16.0.15, I cannot access 172.16.0.1.

If I connect a host with ip 169.254.243.55, I can access the host through 169.254.243.53, so it seems that the vlan atleast works.

But I cannot figure out why this 169.254.243.53 address is added to the vlan5 interface and why I can't access 172.16.0.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Naturally I don't know your *exact* setup, but I think two things are going on here. My setup is similar to yours in that I have a native (untagged) VLAN with subnet 192.168.1.0/24 and VLAN20 running on the same interface with subnet 192.168.2.0/24.

Firstly the 169.254.243.53 address is an automatically-assigned link local address. I've disabled this on mine with `LinkLocalAddressing=no` as below:

```
# cat eth0.network 
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=yes

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.14/24
Gateway=192.168.1.1
DHCP=no
DNS=192.168.1.7
NTP=192.168.1.7
LLDP=yes
EmitLLDP=yes
LinkLocalAddressing=no
VLAN=vlan20
```

I'm *not* using DHCP on this device to configure the interface, so I have to configure things like DNS, NTP and the default gateway, which brings me to the second thing: what does your routing table look like, i.e. the output of `ip route`, on *both* devices?